# Processing.js Can't Access a Global JavaScript Variable

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a switch statement inside my Processing file which changes a variable named 'zooText'. zooText is declared in a JavaScript file named text.js. However, when for some reason, Processing is unable to access, or change, the variable.

The expected behavior would for zooText to change to whatever it is set to in the switch statement. However, the `<p>` only says "undefined".

Here is the switch statement:

```
 switch(sceneNum){
            case 1:
              zooText = "Welcome to the office. This is where we organize all our files. Important files include our certification by the AZA (Association of Zoos & Aquariums), and other"
                    + " important documents which certify we keep our animals healthy and happy";
                    break;
            case 2:
                    zooText = "This is the education area. Here we teach children about the importance of conservation, and protecting our planet. According to some people,"  
         + "we're really influential!";
                    break;
            case 3:
                    zooText = "Scene 3";
                    break;
            case 4:
                    display = "This is the Aquatic Area. Although most of these animals have natural roaming areas of hundreds of miles, we like to keep them in small enclosures";
                    break;
```

And here is the relevant JavaScript:

```
var zooText;

function changeText(){ 
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = zooText;
}
setTimeout(changeText, 100);
```

And finally, the relevant HTML:

```
<head>
              <title>Zoo Ethics</title>

              <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css'>
           <script src="processing.js" width="1000" height="800"></script>
           <script src='text.js'></script>
      </head>

      <body style="background-color:#e0eaf9">
              <h1>Explore the Zoo!</h1>

              <p id="demo"></p>
             <canvas id="sketch" data-processing-sources="zoos.pde"></canvas>
          <script src='text.js'></script>
```

I've been struggling with this for hours. I've kind of narrowed down the problem to maybe the sketch not being loaded before the JavaScript, or something of a similar manner.

Comment: Maybe try var zooText = ""; so it's defined before changing

Comment: @DavidWhite I tried that but it just remains blank, meaning the HTML has no problem accessing the JavaScript, but the Processing is for some reason not able to change the JavaScript

Comment: What is the intention of  `width="1000" height="800"` on a `script` tag?

Comment: `processing.js` relies on `text.js`, therefore **`text.js` must be included *before* `processing.js`**.

Comment: You have `<script src='text.js'></script>` twice in your HTML.

Comment: please try to import all of your required js file just before ending </body> tag. it will definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the text.js file first and then the processing.js

```
<script src='text.js'></script>
<script src="processing.js" width="1000" height="800"></script>
```

Comment: What is the intention of `width="1000" height="800"` on a `script` tag?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a workaround by simply including pure JavaScript in the .pde file. I created a variable named zooText, completely deleted the text.js file, and then simply made the .pde file update the `<p>` in the draw() function.

Answer (score 0):

This truly depends on how you call your scripting. If it is just base code inside Processing.js then it will run the moment it is loaded, even before the DOM and all other scripts are loaded. One option is to reverse the order they are loaded as stated. However this can (for various reasons such as server lag) still potentially produce the same issue. If this is how it's run then you might look into placing the base/original command inside an `init()` function. Then have event run on document ready:
Inside processing.js:

```
function init(){
    //call processing.js functions/commands here
}
//remaining processing.js function definitions here
if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
  init()
} else {
  // the document hasn't finished loading/parsing yet so let's add an event handler
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init)
}
```

Doing it this way will help ensure all scripting is loaded before running. If you have/user jQuery the last part can be simplified with something like `$(document).ready(function(){init()});`

Answer (score 0):

```
  <head>
    <title>Zoo Ethics</title>

     <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css'>
     <script src='text.js'></script> <---I MOVED ABOVE PROCESS.JS
     <script src="processing.js" width="1000" height="800"></script>

  </head>

  <body style="background-color:#e0eaf9">
          <h1>Explore the Zoo!</h1>
          <p id="demo"></p>
         <canvas id="sketch" data-processing-sources="zoos.pde"></canvas>
      <script src='text.js'></script> <---THIS SEEMS LIKE A DUPLICATE
```